Asymptotics of Green functions near diagonal
I heard a statement from a colleague that for Green function for Laplacian on scalars on a compact Riemannian manifold near the diagonal
\begin{equation}
G(x,y) = log\rho(x,y) (\sum_{n=d-2}^1\frac{a_n(x) }{\rho^{n}(x,y)}(1+reg(x,y)) )+ \sum_{n=d-2}^1\frac{b_n(x) }{\rho^{n}(x,y)}(1+reg(x,y)) + reg(x,y)
\end{equation}
where $\rho(x,y)$ is the geodesic distance and $reg(x,y),a_n(x),b_n(x)$ are a regular function. Note the first power of the logarithm.
Q: what is the proof of this statement( i.e. that the logarithm is only to first power)?

This near-diagonal asymptotic form is called the Hadamard parametrix for the Laplacian. Its form is dimension dependent and the logarithmic term doesn't appear in odd dimensions. There are many references discussing it. See for instance Ch.6 of the notes Eigenfunctions of the Laplacian of Riemannian
manifolds by Steve Zeldich. A common textbook reference (cited also by Zeldich) is §5.1 of Garabedian's Partial Differential Equations (Wiley, 1964, 1986 2nd ed.). See also the EOM article Parametrix Method.
